# Mysql: Delete from table where ID, except rows in a selection?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, selection, buddypress, except

The problem

I'm using buddypress for Wordpress it has a table for private messages in side which are thread ids for message threads. Currently there's no limit on how many messages can be in a thread.

I want to create a command that deletes all but the most recent 10 messages in a thread. Below is the logic, but I'm not sure the correct syntax to do it?

Any of you mysql geniuses know the answer?

`DELETE FROM TABLEA WHERE id = X` ***delete everything with thread ID x***

```
EXCEPT 
(SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE id = X ORDER BY date_sent DESC LIMIT 10)
```

***Selects most recent 10 I do not wish deleted.***

Comment: I believe TABLEA has its own primary key ID and the id that you mentioned above is actually just the foreign key, right?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: Please do not deface the original post. If this question gets re-edited, it will be flagged for moderation where the question will be locked and even you won't be able to re-edit. I have rolled it back to a previous revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should working:

```
DELETE FROM TABLEA WHERE id = X AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT TOP 10 id FROM TABLEA ORDER BY date_sent DESC
)
```

The sub-select of this query get the last 10 sent items. The main query have to delete the item with id X except the item is on the result of the sub-select.

Comment: This worked...........DELETE FROM `ywg_bp_messages_messages` WHERE thread_id = 521 AND id NOT IN 
(

    SELECT id FROM 
      (
        SELECT * FROM `ywg_bp_messages_messages` WHERE thread_id = 521 ORDER BY date_sent desc limit 10
      )x
)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the table in buddypress works but I guess TABLEA should have its on primary key id. If TABLEA does have its own primary key id, here's my solution.

```
DELETE FROM TABLEA WHERE id = x AND TABLEA_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT TABLEA_id FROM TABLEA WHERE id = x ORDER BY date_sent DESC LIMIT 10)
```